# Open Instant app from android WebView

Tags: android, webview, instant

Here is the idea what I'm trying to do.

My app is around 24MB. I want to break it into modules using google instant app. My idea is I will implement a `WebView` in which I will load my website which is a dashboard. Now what I want is when a person clicks on any item from the dashboard, the related instant app is loaded. So the user will install only the module which he needed.

Now coming to the problem- How can I open an instant app for my app `WebView`. I'm able to do it with chrome.

Comment: btw which app you want to open?

Comment: It is my instant app feature which I want to open from an android webview

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it. Just set the webview chrome client and it will able to detect instant app from the link.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```